# Eigenvalues of a particular tridiagonal matrix with a variation on one of its diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

I am trying to obtain the eigenvalues of this particular $n\times n$ tridiagonal matrix 
\begin{eqnarray}
A & = &   
\begin{bmatrix}
1+a^{2} & -a & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
-a & 1+a^{2} & -a & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -a & 1+a^{2} &  \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & 1+a^{2} & -a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & -a & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
and my concern is the bottom right entry with a 1 instead of $1+a^{2}$. Is it possible to work out these eigenvalues? When the bottom right entry is $1+a^{2}$ it is known that the eigenvalues are given by 
$\lambda_{s}=1+a^{2}-2 \ a \ Cos(s\pi/(n+1))$ but I have been unable to confirm a similar outcome for this variation.